# "Cannot read property 'getToken' of undefined" while integrating firebase in phonegap

Tags: cordova, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am new in phonegap, i am trying to integrate firebase push notification on my application but i am getting error of
     `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getToken' of undefined`

i am following steps from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase), i have also included google json file and firebase plugin.

here is my code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>

         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

         <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

         <script type="text/javascript">
          function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", Fire, false);


    }
            function Fire() {

                alert("Check");

                window.FirebasePlugin.getToken(function(token) {

                alert(token);

                }, function(error) {

                    console.error(error);
                });
    }
        </script>


    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Cordova</h1>

        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please avoid using $(document).ready instead of that you need to use device ready binding as described here https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html

Comment: I am still not getting token of device

Comment: I have updated my code

Answer (score 0):

You must use funtion fire after deviceready.
for example:

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();

},

notifications: function(){

},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);

},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {

        mkLog("deviceready");
       window.FirebasePlugin.getTokenfunction(token) {
            // save this server-side and use it to push notifications to this device
            mkLog('Token:'+ token);
        }, function(error) {
            mkLog('error:' +error);
        });};
```